# Compiling and running Snapper for Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, btrfs, d-bus, snapshot

I am trying to get [snapper](http://en.opensuse.org/openSUSE:Snapper_Development) working in my Mint 14. (The [version from launchpad](https://launchpad.net/~snapper/+archive/stable) is old and not compatible with Ubuntu 12.10. The [OpenSuSe's build project](https://build.opensuse.org/project/show?project=filesystems:snapper) failed to build it, too). So I try my luck with manual compile.

Following the [Snapper Development page](http://en.opensuse.org/openSUSE:Snapper_Development), I've downloaded repo and installed the dependencies.

After `make` finally I've got this error:

```
(...)
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/adam/tmp/snapper/server'
  CXXLD  snapperd
snapperd.cc:125: error: undefined reference to 'boost::thread::interrupt()'
/usr/include/boost/thread/pthread/shared_mutex.hpp:129: error: undefined reference to 'boost::this_thread::disable_interruption::disable_interruption()'
/usr/include/boost/thread/pthread/shared_mutex.hpp:137: error: undefined reference to 'boost::this_thread::disable_interruption::~disable_interruption()'
```

(...)

I've noticed [another quesion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3584365/boost-thread-error-undefined-reference) that suggests adding `-lboost_thread-mt` to linker invocation. Simple enough... and compilation finished successfully.

But after that and `sudo make install` whatever way I try invoke the snapper I get
error `Failure (org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NoReply)`.

And I'm stuck here. Can anyone help me?